# How to update variable in already ran if statement

Tags: javascript

I have issue that I need to get updated some var if someone confirm something
example: I have if statement that checks for some command (!run). If this command is run, then the user has to confirm something and I need to check if it is confirmed, then do something after that confirmation verification... It wont do something after user accept or decline...

```
let verification = "";
manager.on('checkVerification' function(err) =>{
  if(confirmation.state == "accepted"){
      verifivation = "true";
  } else if (confirmation.state == "declined"){
      verification = "false"
      console.log('user declined confirmation')
}
})
if (command = !run ......){
send.confirmation
  if (verification === "true"){
     //do something
  }else if(verification === "false"){
      //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can set interval, then end it.**

```
if (command = !run ......){
send.confirmation
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 3000);                                                      function myTimer() {
  if (verification === "true"){
      clearInterval(myVar);
      //do something
  }else if(verification === "false"){
      clearInterval(myVar);
      //do something
 } 
}
```